# Specific tag to add for my questions

Tags: discussion, support, tags

With this question I would like to know what specific tag I can include in my questions on Physics.SE since most of them are about clarifications or curiosities or doubts that I encounter for my students of an high school of 14 to 18 years old.

I have not seen nothing of similar.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Related: *[Can doubt sometimes mean question?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tag with the appropriate subfield of physics, e.g. [newtonian-mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newtonian-mechanics) or [electromagnetism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electromagnetism).

From the Help Center article [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/tagging):

> #### Avoid meta-tags
>
> Do not use [meta-tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) in questions. Here are some tips to help you determine whether a tag is a meta-tag:
>
> - **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like `[beginner]`, `[subjective]`, and `[best-practices]`, are not helpful by themselves – they do not communicate anything about the content of the question.

Comment: Fantastic :-) and esteemed friend :-)....Thank you very very very much for your answer.